# Apache2 ProxyPass Error500

Tags: apache, onlyoffice

I have an OnlyOffice Document Server running on my server bound to port 8888 via Docker. Now I want to use a Let's Encrypt certificate to ensure a safe connection (self signed certificates won't work). I use the following config in Apache to rewrite office.example.org to office.example.org:8888 but it throws me an error 500

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
 ServerName office.example.org
  ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / https://localhost:8888/
    ProxyPassReverse / https://localhost:8888/ 
</VirtualHost>
```

All necessary modules are enabled.
Has anyone any idea on how to solve this problem or a different idea to solve the Let's Encrypt problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding the following lines to the Apache config file

```
SSLEngine on
SSLProxyEngine on
SSLProxyVerify none
SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
```

and enabling the with Proxy HTTP module with

```
sudo a2enmod proxy_http
```

did the trick!

Comment: Hi, does it mean adding to `apache2.conf`

Comment: Add above Inside your `<VirtualHost></VirtualHost>` block for specific domain...